# problems with rbind in R

Tags: r

i am trying to do the following:

i have a csv file,

```
test<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\Yi Xiang\\Desktop\\testing.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
```

and it prints out as follows

```
test
[1] Date.and.Time       Size.of.sample.file number.of.errors    percentage         
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

on my excel file iet looks like this: (the first four cells)

```
Date.and.Time   Size.of.sample.file number.of.errors    percentage
```

it is written as excel with just 4 headers, no data.

and then i have the following

```
time<-as.character(Sys.time())
test_vector2<-c(time,dim(data_frame())[1],dim(error_report)[1], 100*(dim(error_report)[1]/dim(data_frame())[1]))
test_vector3<-as.data.frame(t(test_vector2))

row.names(test_vector3)<-NULL
colnames(test_vector3)<-names(test)
```

on my R, it prints out as

```
test_vector3
# Date.and.Time Size.of.sample.file number.of.errors       percentage
# 1 2013-06-30 21:44:09                1739              216 12.4209315698677
```

but when i export it to a csv file,

```
write.csv(test2,"testing.csv")
```

it returns me on excel

```
Date.and.Time   Size.of.sample.file number.of.errors    percentage
1   30/6/2013 21:44 1739    216 12.42093157
```

and if i run the code again,

```
test<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\Yi Xiang\\Desktop\\testing.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")

test
# X       Date.and.Time Size.of.sample.file number.of.errors percentage
# 1 1 2013-06-30 21:44:09                1739              216   12.42093
```

which is not what i want, i have an extra X and 1 in the first column

how do i avoid this?

(if this of interest, basically, i want to record down when i perform my test on my raw data file, and track my percentage file without me appending it manually. so as you can see, my new `names(test)` is different from the old one, which is causing me the problem, when i write the csv file how do i avoid the first column? - i have tried to use the `row.names <- NULL`, but it does not work)

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions for your problem:

1. Don't write the rownames into your csv file: 
   `write.csv(test, "testing.csv", row.names=FALSE)` (see `?write.table` for details).
2. Read rownames as rownames. Means you have to tell `read.csv` which column contains the rownames: `read.csv("testing.csv", row.names=1)` (see `?read.table` for details).

Don't combine both (you will use your first column).